# elliptic equation with exponential coefficient

Tags: nonlinear-equations, numerical-modelling, diffusion

I'm trying to solve the following equation
$$\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(e^{au}\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right) = 0$$

Of course, this equation can be solved analytically. I am trying to understand the way of working with exponential coefficients.

For the approximation, I use the **finite volume method** which leads  to

$$F_{i+1/2} - F_{i-1/2} = 0,\qquad F_{i-1/2} = \left.e^{au}\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right|_{i+1/2} $$

For the further linearization, I'm trying the following two methods:

- simple iteration, where $e^u$ is calculated based on the previous iteration
- Newton's method (with the series expansion, dropping terms that are proportional to $\delta u^2$ and smaller)

$$u^{k+1} = u^k + \delta u$$

The first one worked well until some value of $a$, and the second one didn't work at all (I have not found the mistake yet)

**Is there any way to deal with exponential coefficient?**  Will be glad for any advice. Thanks!

Comment: After a bunch of test i come to working Newton method, but it has the same field of correctnes as a simple iteration. And didnt solve equation with strong exponenta.

Comment: If $a$ is too large, your problem is strongly nonlinear, and you probably need to use a method such as line search to stabilize the Newton iteration. The same is true for a fixed point method like you do in the first approach, where it would be called "damping".

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I honestly suppose that methods such as line search needed to improve convergence? I using some simple dumping method, but it seems like i need some special current approximation method  to handle with strong nonlinearity. Or using a better approximation for derivatives. (I know about exponential scheme but still in search for deeper understanding of the problem)

Comment: For strongly nonlinear problems, there is no way around damping or line search.